# Drag and Drop on a grid

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, viewgroup

I am currently developing an Android APP and I have ran into a bit of a snag. I am using the drag and drop feature to drag different items around and place them into a different layout. I want the layout where I drop the items to be setup in a grid. Where I can drop an item in the general area and it would snap into that location on the grid.

I have done this, but I feel like it is really clunky and there must be a much easier way to get this accomplished. This is how I have it now..

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.david.seniorproject.Controller_LayoutFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_controller__layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout">

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/relative1"
                    android:layout_column="0"></RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/relative2"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/relative3"
                    android:layout_column="2" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/relative4"
                    android:layout_column="3" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/relative5"
                    android:layout_column="4" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/relative6"
                    android:layout_column="5" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:id="@+id/relative7"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:id="@+id/relative8"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:id="@+id/relative9"
                    android:layout_column="2" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:id="@+id/relative10"
                    android:layout_column="3" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:id="@+id/relative11"
                    android:layout_column="4" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:id="@+id/relative12"
                    android:layout_column="5" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:id="@+id/relative13"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:id="@+id/relative14"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:id="@+id/relative15"
                    android:layout_column="2" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:id="@+id/relative16"
                    android:layout_column="3" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:id="@+id/relative17"
                    android:layout_column="4" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:id="@+id/relative18"
                    android:layout_column="5" />

            </GridLayout>
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:backgroundTint="#ff5500" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:paddingRight="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_items"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
                    android:id="@+id/button2" /></LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, I placed a bunch of layouts evenly throughout the GridLayout. It works, but I feel like there is a better way. The button is just dummy data to test the drag and drop feature.

So my question is, is there a way to setup a gridLayout, or a different Layout to do the same as my setup, without all the extra layouts, or would it be better to just create a custom ViewGroup.

Comment: I would user a Recyclerview and set the layoutManager to GridLayoutManager.  Ex http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for. I am going to try it out and see. Thank you!

Comment: The only issue with the Recyclerview, is I am unable to figure out how to drag from outside the view, and drop into the Recyclerview. Any ideas? I have looked and cannot find anything on it.